# Syntax error on token "{", throw expected before this token at JSON file in eclipse

Tags: json, eclipse, geojson

Why the the eclipse IDE tell that the following GeoJSON data has a syntax error ?
The file was generated from XML file in GML structure by the website: http://ogre.adc4gis.com/

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
    "features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gml_id": "1", "ogc_fid": 1, "name": "Bordeaux", "id": 124 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -0.608315, 44.857522 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gml_id": "2", "ogc_fid": 2, "name": "Barbezieux", "id": 0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -0.021418, 45.477577 ] } }
]
}
```

The error is "**Syntax error on token "{", throw expected before this token**", and it occurred in the first line.

Comment: Could you give us some context ?

Comment: I create simple dynamic web application in eclipse. the GeoJSON data is in JS file. There is a javascript code that use openlayers library, and use the JS file. It work fine and the browser is able to parse that JS file, but eclipse saying that there is syntax error in the JS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cut your code and replace with the following.

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "crs":{
      "type":"name",
      "properties":{
         "name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
      }
   },
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            "gml_id":"1",
            "ogc_fid":1,
            "name":"Bordeaux",
            "id":124
         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -0.608315,
               44.857522
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            "gml_id":"2",
            "ogc_fid":2,
            "name":"Barbezieux",
            "id":0
         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -0.021418,
               45.477577
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

you missed one curly braces that's why you getting error!!

Thanks..

Comment: Create New Json File and paste and check!!

Comment: I created new file with json ending, and associated it withe javascript editor (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357521/is-there-a-decent-json-editor-around). now there is no errors.

Answer (score 0):

If I add to Eclipse a `.js` file with a valid json content ;

example

```
{"oo":"ii"}
```

Then eclipse report the following error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token "{", throw expected before this token
    - Syntax error on token "", { expected after this token
```

Note that a bug is reported on this subject cf. [Bugzilla – Bug 427543](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=427543)

in addition, please notice that http://jsonlint.com/ is a free online service that could help to validate and format any json content (maybe there is a way to embed this in Eclipse?)